# I want to make my Iphone in German Language , Which is currently in English Language

Tags: ios

I want to make my Iphone in German Language , Which is currently in English Language,how can i make it ? Currently German Language option is Not available in Settings/others/languages.

Answer (score 2):

Settings → General → Language & Region → iPhone Language → search for German.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]